# How to print contents of SQS message body in .Net

Tags: .net, amazon-sqs

I have been trying print Object created from sqs message body below in .Net.

```
"Records": [
    {

        *****"body": "{\n    \"Records\": [\n        {\n            \"eventVersion\": \"2.1\",\n            \"eventSource\": \"aws:s3\",\n            \"awsRegion\": \"us-east-1\",\n            \"eventTime\": \"2020-02-18T23:35:07.83Z\",\n            \"eventName\": \"ObjectCreated:Put\",\n            \"userIdentity\": {\n                \"principalId\": \"AWS:AROAI32VQZJAYMFLW7AF6:i-000a08934cf25d02f\"\n            },\n            \"requestParameters\": {\n                \"sourceIPAddress\": \"54.205.64.40\"\n            },\n            \"responseElements\": {\n                \"x-amz-request-id\": \"0102C3F5984E4018\",\n                \"x-amz-id-2\": \"P0M/58sCuaZfOJVKPdkyqPcbiYNLOqmgvYtWXh/0n01rcUwaYchzHj4FEIsBiBYJpwhc1pNh7khhMgC29/DpaYEARa+k5C+L\"\n            },\n            \"s3\": {\n                \"s3SchemaVersion\": \"1.0\",\n                \"configurationId\": \"c88ecc67-0746-4172-97a6-9e45a455483d\",\n                \"bucket\": {\n                    \"name\": \"lbi-power-monitor-csvfiles-dev\",\n                    \"ownerIdentity\": {\n                        \"principalId\": \"ACJ7SDRW56IDB\"\n                    },\n                    \"arn\": \"arn:aws:s3:::lbi-power-monitor-csvfiles-dev\"\n                },\n                \"object\": {\n                    \"key\": \"Moderna+Therapeutics/2020/02/18/PowerMonitor-system-data-20200218-233511.csv\",\n                    \"size\": 77742,\n                    \"eTag\": \"768256930356a4958b299fa13406edc1\",\n                    \"sequencer\": \"005E4C74AFDC76715B\"\n                }\n            }\n        }\n    ]\n}",*****
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you wanting to know how to read the data in the body?

Comment: Yes . I need to get Object .Key which is filename to trigger my lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the body of the message you need to deserialize it. The message is a JSON string. In .Net the most common means of doing this is with the [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library. If you know the element you are looking for you can create a class (or set of classes) to deserialize it to that object. If you don't want to create classes you can use the `Linq` objects and work with those to navigate through the JSON to find the data you are looking for.

**Example That Writes Out The Bucket Name**

```cs
var body = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse("{\n    \"Records\": [\n        {\n            \"eventVersion\": \"2.1\",\n            \"eventSource\": \"aws:s3\",\n            \"awsRegion\": \"us-east-1\",\n            \"eventTime\": \"2020-02-18T23:35:07.83Z\",\n            \"eventName\": \"ObjectCreated:Put\",\n            \"userIdentity\": {\n                \"principalId\": \"AWS:AROAI32VQZJAYMFLW7AF6:i-000a08934cf25d02f\"\n            },\n            \"requestParameters\": {\n                \"sourceIPAddress\": \"54.205.64.40\"\n            },\n            \"responseElements\": {\n                \"x-amz-request-id\": \"0102C3F5984E4018\",\n                \"x-amz-id-2\": \"P0M/58sCuaZfOJVKPdkyqPcbiYNLOqmgvYtWXh/0n01rcUwaYchzHj4FEIsBiBYJpwhc1pNh7khhMgC29/DpaYEARa+k5C+L\"\n            },\n            \"s3\": {\n                \"s3SchemaVersion\": \"1.0\",\n                \"configurationId\": \"c88ecc67-0746-4172-97a6-9e45a455483d\",\n                \"bucket\": {\n                    \"name\": \"lbi-power-monitor-csvfiles-dev\",\n                    \"ownerIdentity\": {\n                        \"principalId\": \"ACJ7SDRW56IDB\"\n                    },\n                    \"arn\": \"arn:aws:s3:::lbi-power-monitor-csvfiles-dev\"\n                },\n                \"object\": {\n                    \"key\": \"Moderna+Therapeutics/2020/02/18/PowerMonitor-system-data-20200218-233511.csv\",\n                    \"size\": 77742,\n                    \"eTag\": \"768256930356a4958b299fa13406edc1\",\n                    \"sequencer\": \"005E4C74AFDC76715B\"\n                }\n            }\n        }\n    ]\n}");

Console.WriteLine(body["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]);
```

Comment: So to print bucketname from body i used code:record["body"]["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"].ToString(); but it gives me error cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Still Same error meesage Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.get_Item(Object key)

Comment: So I am adding this code to parse sqs message var body=  JToken.Parse(record["body"]["Records"][0]["body"].ToString());

Comment: SQS message body {
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "a860f1aa-a800-4e73-8644-4706b6f0f948",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBM7Q5vRTw7NjCrLOGeBu6EIZLdNZl3fGa+Kay/Nk9uUcrJzuWt+X7cEUBlDY
 
        }
    ]
}

Comment: That's actually a collection of SQS messages. Each { "messageId":... } is a single SQS message. Each of those has a `body` ( { "body": "message body" } ). *That* is what you need to parse. So `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(event.Records[0].body)`.